# Exchange 2013 web apps in the outlook client prompt for login

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013

We're in the process of migrating from Exchange 2007 to 2013.  We noticed that outlook web apps are now being integrated into the Outlook client.  The problem I'm seeing is we're being prompted to login to OWA in order access the feature.  Is there any way to enable an auto login, while still keeping forms based authentication for OWA?[image]

Answer (score 1):

"... You can configure Integrated Windows authentication for Outlook Web App in Microsoft Exchange Server 2010. Integrated Windows authentication enables the server to authenticate users who are signed in to the network without prompting them for their user name and password and without transmitting information that isn't encrypted over the network."

[Here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/49702e90-8874-4cd7-8c8d-c42dad3b383f/how-to-auto-login-in-owa-when-user-type-url-of-owa-it-should-loged-in-without-prompt-password?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy)

Comment: so the tricky part here is I DO want users to have to login using forms based auth for normaw OWA, but I don't want them to have to login for these web apps

Comment: I do not think it's possible.

Comment: It works in our test environment which is why its really strange.  We used the same scripts to setup test and prod, yet prod shows the above and test works fine.  Very strange.

Comment: Hmm ... I'm kinda puzzled. Were you able to export the site settings to compare?

Comment: the thing is, I don't know know specifically what has an effect on this feature to know what to compare.  Meaning I don't know the specifica dependencies.  Like which virtual directory, or what cmdlet to check.  I've checked authentication and that's the same, redirects are the same.  Honestly not sure what too compare.

Comment: Perhaps try to Google something along the lines of: compare IIS SETTINGS.